# Remover observações específicas de Data Frame em R

Tags: r, dataframe

Boa noite, pessoal. Preciso de uma forcinha de vocês.

Tenho um data frame no formato de dados em painel onde meus N são os municípios de São Paulo e T são os anos da minha amostra. Para ilustrar, minha base de dados segue a seguinte forma:

```
N                T         Urbanização
Adamantina      2000           92.43
Adamantina      2001           92.71
Adamantina      2002           92.88
Adamantina      2003           93.01
Adolfo          2000           88.02
Adolfo          2001           88.16
Adolfo          2002           88.22
Adolfo          2003           88.44
.               .              .
.               .              . 
.               .              .
```

Gostaria de um código que retirasse da minha amostra as observações sobre o ano de 2003 para todos os municípios, sendo assim, o que quero é que estas observações sejam excluídas da minha base.

Agradeço qualquer contribuição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você deseja remover da lista todos que forem iguais a 2003, é só selecionar todos que tiverem a coluna T diferente de 2003.

```
data <- data[data$T!=2003,]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que `data` seja o seu `data.frame`:

```
data <- data[!data$T== 2003, ]
```

ou se a coluna for caracter:

```
data <- data[!data$T== "2003", ]
```

Comment: Excelente, amigo. Muito obrigado!